# connect to postgresql database with different locale

Tags: postgresql, locale, windows-10

I have some old database that I need to connect to (postgres 9.1). I have no problem to start server with

```
pg_ctl start -D D:\datadir\pgdata\data -w
```

but when I try to connect, it gives:

```
psql -U postgres -p 15432
psql: FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.
```

new version of postgres would not start server (incompatible data version).
I'm using windows 10, with postgres 9.1 binaries.

How would it be possible to connect, migrate, upgrade such database, to access it data?

Comment: I have the same problem! ANY SUGESTION?

Comment: sorry, I really don't remember how I solved it. I guess it was either I connected to it from VM with correct locale or somehow dumped/backup and recreated with another.

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue today. Except my error was for en_GB:

```
The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_GB.UTF-8",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
```

I solved it with

```
localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_GB en_GB.UTF-8
```

You will need to change it depending on your language setting.

Restart the postgresql service after.

Comment: 'localedef' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: localedef is a utility available on POSIX shells. See https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/localedef/